# Write a function which takes two points as input and returns if they are diagnal to each other or not in java

Tags: java

There is a m*n grid
This pont in the grid is represented by two coordinates.for example (4,5).

Write a function which takes two points as input and returns if they are diagnal to each other or not

**For example:**

points (0,1) is diagonal to (2,3) but not to (2,2).

**My code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give X-coordinate of first point:");
    int x1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Give Y-coordinate of first point:");
    int y1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Give X-coordinate of second point:");
    int x2 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Give Y-coordinate of second point:");
    int y2 = sc.nextInt();
    if (diagCheck(x1, y1, x2, y2)) {
        System.out.println("yes,the points are diagonal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no,the points are not diagonal");
    }

}

public static boolean diagCheck(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    boolean diag = false;
    if (a * d == b * c) {
        diag = true;
    }
    return diag;
}
```

But its not working for all cases...

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: What means "But its not working for all cases"

Comment: there is some problem with logic its not accepting some points like points (0,1) is diagonal to (2,3) but its not accepting.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `abs((a-c))==abs((b-d))` ? This is in the case when you have Point1(a,b) and Point2(c,d)

Comment: Your diagonal condition is uncertain,how are you checking diagonals without any third point of reference???

Comment: what is  abs in abs((a-c))==abs((b-d))

Comment: abs is a method in java.Use `Math.abs` in place of abs!

Comment: i think the question provided to me is not right..it needs a third point too..

Comment: As a reminder to address your comments : `Math.abs` returns the absolute value of an expression, but you could as well compare the square of the expression, as it is always positive as well. You could change your test to : `(a-c)*(a-c)==(b-d)*(b-d)`. As a side note concerning the `Math` library, it is standard to java, and every install will have it so you don't need to worry about portability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean diagCheck(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {        
    return Math.abs(x1-x2) == Math.abs(y1-y2);
}
```

Comment: this is telling that (4,5) and (8,10) are not diagonal..  is it right

Comment: also i want to know can i do it without using predefined functions

Comment: you can always code abs yourself... but there's realy no point in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare the absolute difference Math.abs(x1-x2) with the absolute difference Math.abs(y1-y2); they are equal if and only if the points are diagonal to each other.

Comment: Math.abs(x1,x2) can be replaced with (x1>x2?x1-x2:x2-x1)

Comment: can u explain (x1>x2?x1-x2:x2-x1) please

Comment: The ternary operator ?: consists of three parts: a?b:c means "if a, then b, else c"; in my case, it means: "if x1 is larger than x2, then calculate x1-x2, else x2-x1" so the difference is always >=0.